# Execute IQueryable on DB Layer and return a new One (eraly execute)

Tags: linq, nhibernate, iqueryable

I wnat that my DB Layer Returns a IQueryable of its DTO Objects. I use NHibernate wich has support for Linq. But the problem is, i've to close the session when my DB Layer is leaved, and so the IQueryable does not work any more.
But I also could not return a List because then the Querys will not be Executed on the SQL Server.

So is it possible that i Return a IQueryable, exceute the Expression with the Nhibernate LINQ and Return a New IQueryable??

maybe something like this:

```
public IQueryable<TagDTO> Tags
    {
        get
        {
            using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
            {
                return new ExceuteQueryable<TagDTO>(session.Query<TagDTO>());
                //return session.Query<TagDTO>();
            }
        }
    }
```

where ExceuteQueryable should use it's Expression Tree to execute the Query, get a List of the Results and return a new iqueryable of the List?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want that the Expression comes to my Datalayer, and is executed on the Server. But I want that is Executed imidiatly and not first when the IQueryable is enumerated.
But i can not return a List from my datalayer, because then the expression did not go to the Server. 
And I also can not use the IQueryable<T> from Linq, because than I can not dispose the session before the enumeration is done!

Comment: where is the expression to execute? Properties have no parameters to hand over the Expression. After returning the IQueryable, the connection is lost and it is useless

Comment: Yes I know that Properties have no Parameters. But with the orginal IQueryable, it also works that Get the Expression Tree. I think that the IQuerable works somewhat like a Callback, where the Object is Returned and then the Expression Tree is used? Or am I wrong.

Answer (score 0):

executing early is the same as returning a list. Without a connection to the database (session) how can you possibly execute a query on it? Do not micromanage the session like this instead use/hold a session for the whole buisiness operation and there 's no problem with closed transactions anymore.

Returning IQueryable from the DAL will lead to pain sooner than you think because the dataaccess has absolutly no context to optimise the access (eager fetching, filtering, ToList() for iterating multiple times). Also consistent caching is near impossible without context.

Comment: I have a connection to the Database, but only in the Datalayer. That means, when the getter is leaved, the session object should be disposed!

Comment: @JochenKühner And that is often the problem... Letting the datalayer define the session and transaction boundaries are very often the wrong thing to do. See for instance the "open session in view" or "session per request" patterns.

Comment: Maybe thats wrong, but I could not change the whole app! I only wanted to know, is there a Solution for my problem?

Comment: apart from returning a List you could implement your own IQueryable Provider which serializes and deserializes the whole query. This will be a huge project depending on the complexity of the queries involved. You will almost certainly fall over SELECT N+1 and caching issues. Errorhandling(r.g. databaseexceptions) will be scathered over every `.ToList()`/`.ToArray()` call throughout your business logic

Comment: Maybe this could help me: http://interlinq.codeplex.com/ It supports Linq over WCF, and for this the Querys already have to be Serialized?